# Показать diff только измененённых файлов, т. е. НЕ добавленных или удалённых

Tags: git, git-diff

Как используя `git-diff` показать только изменения
в файлах, которые были изменены, то есть игнорируя добавленыые
и удалённые файлы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте флаг [`diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203)
со значением `M`:

```sh
$ git diff --diff-filter=M --staged
```

Comment: `git whatchanged -D -M -C ...` (`-M` и `-C` по вкусу)  А вы давно сами с собой разговариваете?

Comment: @0andriy  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer